# how to retrieve data from 4 table with Eloquent relations in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am working with laravel 8 and have the following table with their models structure

```
Orders
Id, store_id,client_id,delivery_date,created_at

order_details
Id,order_id,product_id,quantity,total_price

Products,
Id,product_name,product_image

users 
id,name,phone,address
```

I want to retrieve data from 4 tables according to order id to display order with it's details as following json format for example

```
{
   "id":1,
   "delivery_date":"20-06-2021",
   "created_at":"10-06-2021",
   "order_details":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "product_name":"TV",
         "product_image":"http://xxxx.com/images/tv.jpg",
         "quantity":1,
         "total_price":3000
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "product_name":"playstation",
         "product_image":"http://xxxx.com/images/playstation.jpg",
         "quantity":3,
         "total_price":5000
      }
   ],
   "client":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"john",
      "address":"somewhere"
   }
}
```

but I don't know how to get these data write code using relations and eloquent in laravel

Comment: put a many to many relation between order and products with a pivot table `order_details` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many and a simple 1 to many between order and client. For how to code it, read the documentation and if you have issue with your tries, post a question.

Comment: i will check it

Answer (score 2):

Some basic idea to help you.

**Orders Model**

```
public function products(){
    
    $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'order_details')->withPivot('quantity', 'total_price')->withTimestamps();;
}

public function client(){
    
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'client_id','id');
}
```

So you can do some think like  below to access it

```
Order::with(['products','client'])->find($orderId);
```

Similar question but on relationship insert
Ref:[Attempt to read property "price" on null in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919919/attempt-to-read-property-price-on-null-in-laravel/67919954)

Comment: order_details should not be a model, it's a pivot table between order and products. for example, you can't have two entries representing the same product linked to the same order. that is the quantity field role.

Comment: @N69S.thanks for pointing out my mistake .