# I make order management system, how to total The price in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I make order management system in laravel. This is my table structure is
When user gives order The controller will fill 2 tables 1- **orders** , 2- **orderitems** in orders table there are 2 fields **user_id** and **total** (price). and in orderitems controller will create different columns for product example if user place 2 product than controller will create 2 row in orderitems table there are 5 fields **order_id** , **product_id** , **quantity** , **price** , **total** (for particular product)

This is my orders table
[image]

this is my orderitems table

[image]

the doubt is that how i can add price of different columns of orderitems table and show it in total of orders table
this is my OrderController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::create([
        'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
        'total' => **Doubt here**,
    ]);
    $size = count(collect($request)->get('quantity'));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $orderitem = Orderitem::create([
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'product_id' => $request->get('product_id')[$i],
            $quantity = $request->get('quantity')[$i],
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            $price = Product::find($request->get('product_id')[$i])->price,
            'price' => $price,
            'total' => $quantity * $price,
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation.I think this will be ok

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::create([
        'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
        'total' => 0,
    ]);
    $total = 0;
    $size = count(collect($request)->get('quantity'));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $orderitem = Orderitem::create([
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'product_id' => $request->get('product_id')[$i],
            $quantity = $request->get('quantity')[$i],
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            $price = Product::find($request->get('product_id')[$i])->price,
            'price' => $price,
            'total' => $quantity * $price,
        ]);
        $total += $orderitem['quantity']*$orderitem['price'];
    }
    $order['total'] = $total;
    $order->save()

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

but in some more reality scenario.we will do order calculation more complex such as discocunt.so we will know order total before saved to database.
if you have more question.please comment to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using relationship then you can do the following

```
 $order = Order::create([
        'user_id' => 1,

    ]);

    $order->product()->sync([
        1=>['quantity'=>2, 'price'=>20,'total'=>40],
        2=>['quantity'=>1, 'price'=>10,'total'=>10],
    ]);

    $order->total=$order->product()->sum('total');
    $order->save();
```

As i  posted relationship in other post which relating to this then you can do the above method. Ref:[Attempt to read property "price" on null in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919919/attempt-to-read-property-price-on-null-in-laravel)